# How to disable Ascending or Descending order in MySQL query output?

Tags: mysql

How to disable the default ascending order of output in a MySQL query and the output must appear as it was arranged in the SQL query somewhere?

When I query something like this one...

```
select postalcode, customername, contactname, * from customers
where postalcode in ('13008','12209','05022')
```

...the output will look like this in the picture below.

[image]

How to make a query in such a way that the output will now look like in the picture below?

[image]

Thank you all!

Comment: So `ORDER BY FIELD(postalcode,'13008','12209','05022')`

Comment: SELECT postalcode, customername, contactname, * from customers
WHERE postalcode in ('13008','12209','05022')

ORDER BY

CASE
 WHEN '13008' THEN 1
 WHEN '12209' THEN 2
 WHEN '05022' THEN 3

END

Comment: That would be the query....Thanks!